# How to reset the iframe properties at certain context of my web page. without using javascript

Tags: php, css, iframe

I am working on responsive design.. My Page contains iFrames

Example :

```
    <iframe class="frame" src="www.google.com?embed=true&width=800&height=600" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
   </iframe>
```

You can observe that i am also assigning the style as width and height:100% so that the iframe will be displayed responsive manner.

The problem is when my iframe is like

```
    <iframe class="frame" src="www.google.com?embed=true" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
   </iframe>
```

The iframe seems to adjust properly on iPhone device's width.

and if i do mention height and width it will not adjust to iphone's width as i have defined the properties.

I tried this way:
CSS

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 400px), only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
      .frame{
             width:320px;

             }
   }
```

**But the iframe is popping out of the container-Frame.**

So i just want to know how to reset the style for the class "frame" so that iframe that is being displayed on iphone will will have

```
<iframe src="www.google.com?embed=true"></iframe>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .div {
            width: 300px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

here are more

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

Comment: any other suggestion, The iframe url will be entered from a form input field. It is not controlled by me. hence i just take the value from the database and display them.  Hope you got me clearly !

Comment: you can not apply css to iframe's content, browsers don't allow that option.

Comment: Oh really !. Thank you so much. I just came to know it now.